# ATI Radeon Graphics card support for virtualbox running Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, opengl

I am interested in doing OpenGL programming in Ubuntu and have no wish to create an instance of Ubuntu alongside my Windows at boot time. So, is it possible to get the support of my ATI Radeon graphics card installed in my Windows host from virtual box Ubuntu 10.04? I find it laborious dealing with the mammoth Visual Studio 2010.

The answer may be obvious and I found some hint on enabling 3D acceleration in Virtual Box mode which is the best a Virtual Box can have. Anybody interested in enlightening me further?

Comment: So any probable answers yet ?

Answer (score 0):

see the following: [Cannot setup PCI Passthrough for display adapter in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/663837/cannot-setup-pci-passthrough-for-display-adapter-in-virtualbox)

and also: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013

It seems it would be possible if you did it the other way round, with ubuntu as the host, also there is better support for vga passthrough in xen or kvm (other virtualisation software, google them) than virtual box, although virtual box does seem to support the feature in theory, see

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

Comment: @Hennes, if he has a modern intel processor then couldn't he just use the inbuilt display card?

Answer (score 0):

Technically: Yes, this is possible, but:

## 1 from Sean's links:

"When running on **Linux hosts**, with a recent enough kernel (at least version 2.6.31) experimental host PCI devices passthrough is available".  So Virtual box does not support it yet on your current host OS.

## 2 Headless:

Are you going to run the windows setup headless? If not, what are you going to use as display option for windows after dedicating the graphics card to the guest OS ?