# passthrough graphics card to virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, graphics-card

So I'm trying to get my laptops NVIDIA fx 880m to pass to a virtual box running window seven on a linux mint 17 install.

So far everything seems to be (maybe) heading in the right direction:

the device passed through happily, when I booted the virtual box it installed a bunch of new drivers, but when I try to install the NVIDIA driver on the guest it can't find the card. I looked under the device manager and there's no listing for the nvidia card under the pci bus, my guess would be that I need to disable it in the host so that it can be passed through to the guest (the virtual box manual said they can't be shared) but I'm not sure how to do so. Can anybody help with this? This question does not seem to me to be a duplicate of [Cannot setup PCI Passthrough for display adapter in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/663837/cannot-setup-pci-passthrough-for-display-adapter-in-virtualbox), because here the given solution was that it was not possible with a windows host, however in this case the host is linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot setup PCI Passthrough for display adapter in VirtualBox](http://superuser.com/questions/663837/cannot-setup-pci-passthrough-for-display-adapter-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported in Virtualbox.

Your only alternative virtualization software that supports this that I am aware of are **Qemu** and **Xen** and possibly **VMWare**. Most success tales of passing through GPUs to virtual machines come from either Qemu or Xen so I would suggest you turn towards that until Virtualbox supports this.

There is [a blog devoted to the subject](http://vfio.blogspot.com/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-1-hardware.html)(that is their 2015 tutorial on how to do this with qemu as a focus) which you may want to look into.

Keep in mind that VGA Passthrough is still very experimental technology and it requires Motherboard/CPU combinations that support very specific features, and usually it also requires a custom kernel configuration to actually be able to access these features from within Linux (to be able to use them in the virtual machine).

In light of this, please try not to overcommit. You are very likely to run into bugs or issues that can render either your physical or virtual system unstable or in some ways inoperable while using VGA Passthrough. Don't expect it to work completely, nor easily. You need luck for that to really happen.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.

You can pass through USB devices, no problem. But when you start dealing with PCI and PCIe devices, they will not get passed through. In theory, if you disabled your graphics card until you booted your host OS, then enabled your graphics card "magically", your VM would still need full control over it (which your OS won't give you). It's not going to be possible given current technology

Comment: hey thanks, so do you mean to say that, although virtual box will allow pass through of pci devices, the current technology doesn't allow it to pass through total control? Maybe I misunderstood, but it seemed like this guy
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56777/enabling-iommu-in-the-kernel-for-graphics-card-pass-through
seemed to get almost there...

Comment: Windows won't give up that kind of control. I could see it *theoretically* possible if you had multiple types of video cards detected, but they get initialized with the BIOS/EFI when your system boots, before Windows would be *able* to give up control to another VM

Comment: Yes but I'm passing through from Linux to windows, so wouldn't it be Linux giving up control?

Comment: Sorry, yes. But either way, the OS will not give up control to a full PCI device. It's still going to intercept requests to it, as PCI actually maps to part of the CPU, literally.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/680857/24010

Comment: yes I saw this post, but they are saying that it is impossible on a windows host, not linux

Comment: read the comment, from the vbox dev team - it's experimental

Comment: but experimental means it can be done, right? unless I misunderstood...

Comment: It isn't supported, because the people designing the software can't get it working more often than not

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/grid-technology.html NVIDIA support PCI-passthrough

Comment: "I'm trying to get my laptops NVIDIA fx 880m". A laptop won't support it

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=69064 This is from the virtual box forums, still no answer, but also no one saying it can't be done...

Comment: he says he has it working on kvm, might try that if I can't get it working on virtual box, but I still think it should just be a matter of disabling the graphics card on the host, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems that it can be done, however what is important is the graphics card and chipset that are being used. In my case, processor and motherboard are fine, but graphics card is not :( but good news for the rest of you. Also it seems that the feature is better supported in xen or kvm than virtual box, see http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013